# Working on an open source game

Tags: game-design, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get involved with open source game projects?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/496/how-can-i-get-involved-with-open-source-game-projects)

I am trying to get involved in working on an open sourced basic game, but I've never attempted this before. I haven't the slightest clue how to go about this, what I should know (not programming-wise, just in general) and such...

Not sure if this question fits your Q/A format but, what do you suggest? Are there any really good well documented open source games that are basic that I could work on, preferably something that is RTS? And if I've never done this before, is there anything I should look in to that applies to open source projects in general?

Answer (score 4):

Sourceforge, Github, Google Code, and Assembla are rife with open source games of all types, and likely many of those teams would eagerly accept new membership.

Or failing that, the same places enable you to start your own open source game, should you decide that is your direction.

Github is especially easy... find something you want to work on, and fork it.

A warning, however: in researching these places and the projects on them, you are wandering into a vast wasteland of broken dreams and wishes.

Don't let that deter you, though.

Comment: hah, +1 for "vast wasteland of broken dreams and wishes"